# Terraform "value of 'count' cannot be computed: why?

Tags: terraform

I have the following resource specification in my templates:

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "allow_app_server" {
  count = "${length(split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.outbound_ip_addresses))}"

  depends_on = ["azurerm_app_service.backend"]

  name                = "${format("Allow App Service Plan %d", count.index)}"
  start_ip_address    = "${element(split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.possible_outbound_ip_addresses), count.index)}"
  end_ip_address      = "${element(split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.possible_outbound_ip_addresses), count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.environment_resource_group_name}"
  server_name         = "${var.db_server_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "backend" {
   # properties ommitted for brevity
}
```

Now when I run `terraform plan`, it errors with the message

> azurerm_sql_firewall_rule.allow_app_server: value of 'count' cannot be computed

Why? What can I do to fix this (that doesn't require me to partially deploy the template)?

Comment: I wonder if the `depends_on` is evaluated as part of the individual resource creation, ie after the `count` has been evaluated

Comment: That is a very common terraform problem - read the length() carefully, in some cases you need to add [] to the parameter. Also, you can define a local parameter and use that.

Comment: @victorm It seems that the main problem is that the resource it's referring to (`azurerm_app_service.backend`) doesn't exist yet, so it can't read the output property (`outbound_ip_addresses`). If I create the backend service (with `terraform apply -target=...`) successfully and _then_ do `terraform apply` as usual, it works as expected - but I was hoping I wouldn't have to do this in two steps, since that makes it significantly less useful for setting up new environments.

Comment: @TomasAschan can you do a `depends_on` in the `azurerm_sql_firewall_rule` resource to depend on the service before it tries to evaluate that?

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer I already have one (as shown in the OP). It doesn't help, apparently. Or did you mean depend on an additional resource? Which one?

Comment: @TomasAschan it is a bug in terraform, I run into this issue many times, sometimes it works sometimes it does not even if a value is there. Check the documentation for the split() function: "Depending on the use, the string this is being performed within may need to be wrapped in brackets to indicate that the output is actually a list, e.g. a_resource_param = ["${split(",", var.CSV_STRING)}"]. Example: split(",", module.amod.server_ids)"

Comment: @victorm: Thanks for the suggestion, but doing that inline is a syntax error. I tried extracting a local variable, and wrapping the variable value in `[]`, but that still gives me the same error.

Comment: @TomasAschan Here's the [open issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/12570) with many upvotes. When you run `terraform show` does `azurerm_app_service.backend.outbound_ip_addresses` return the correct output? If not then the issue is with the output itself. If so then this error is due to the issue I linked which leaves a possible workaround by changing the `outbound_ip_addresses` output from a comma separated string into a [list](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/variables.html#lists).

Comment: @TomasAschan by converting that output from a comma separated string into a list, you can omit the `split` function or you can try moving the entire count statement into a local variable which might work.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer: You'll notice that the last comment on that issue (from a couple of days before you commented) was written by me ;) The output is not configured by me, but by the Terraform provider. It will (probably) be refactored into being a list variable in a future release, see https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/2513

Comment: @TomasAschan perhaps it's an Azure provider issue than a terraform issue. It looks like it tries to calculate the count before retrieving the backend. If so, then it's probably a bug. Have you opened a ticket with the terraform azure provider project?

Answer (score 1):

you have double quotes issue, try this:

```
count = "${length(split(',', azurerm_app_service.backend.outbound_ip_addresses))}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to wrap with brackets ?

```
resource "azurerm_sql_firewall_rule" "allow_app_server" {
  count = "${length([split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.outbound_ip_addresses)])}"

  depends_on = ["azurerm_app_service.backend"]

  name                = "${format("Allow App Service Plan %d", count.index)}"
  start_ip_address    = "${element(split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.possible_outbound_ip_addresses), count.index)}"
  end_ip_address      = "${element(split(",", azurerm_app_service.backend.possible_outbound_ip_addresses), count.index)}"
  resource_group_name = "${var.environment_resource_group_name}"
  server_name         = "${var.db_server_name}"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "backend" {
   # properties ommitted for brevity
}
`
```